# Fancybox, play a youtube video with start time and autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox to play a youtube video.  Works as expected.  Video pops up and plays great.
However, I would like to use both AUTOPLAY and Start Time when my video is clicked.

Here is the URL I'm trying.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwaKZ4r5fQM&amp;autoplay=1&amp;t=0m47s
```

Autoplay works fine, but the start time is ignored.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do is using fancybox media helpers so

1). Load the fancybox media helper js file :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{your correct path}/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
```

2). Only set your youtube URL without any parameter like :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwaKZ4r5fQM">Start YouTube in fancybox at 47 secs</a>
```

3). Enable the media helper in your fancybox custom initialization script **and** pass the youtube parameters using this format :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            media: true
        },
        youtube: {
            autoplay: 1, // enable autoplay
            start: 47 // set start time in seconds (embed)
        }
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**NOTE** : the media helper will convert the video URL in its *embed* format like :

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/BwaKZ4r5fQM
```

... where the parameter `t={mm}m{ss}s` is not longer valid.

With youtube *embedded player* you can select the *start* time using the [`start`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#start) parameter followed by the *number* **in seconds** of the wanted starting time (as we did in the fancybox initialization script)

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

Comment: For others who will find this answer - please note that for fancybox3 parameters structure will differ: `config.media.youtube.params.start` ( https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#options )